# escaping str format brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to print something like the string below using Python:

```
{"_id":ObjectId("5a43ae09e2bae06ddd400dfc")}
```

At first I thought it would be easy, but it is not.

Here is my first attempt:

```
'{"_id":ObjectId("{}")}'.format('5a43ae09e2bae06ddd400dfc')
```

But I got the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   KeyError: '"_id"'

Then I tried:

```
'\{"_id":ObjectId("{}")\}'.format('5a43ae09e2bae06ddd400dfc')
```

And I got this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>       KeyError: '"_id"'

I managed to make it work with the following code:

```
'{"_id":ObjectId("%s")}' %('5a43ae09e2bae06ddd400dfc')
'{"_id":ObjectId("5a43ae09e2bae06ddd400dfc")}'
```

What's wrong with str format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape your brackets so Python can tell the difference between a format parameter and a character that needs to be printed out, to do that you can just duplicate the brackets as follows:

```
print('{{"_id":ObjectId("{}")}}'.format('5a43ae09e2bae06ddd400dfc'))
```

Here is more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: Thanks! but I still feel a bit strange,  why not as common practice that use '\' to escape brackets